# value withLang is not a member of play.api.mvc.Result

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4

In a Play Framework 2.3 app, I had the following method:

```
def defaultLanguage[T](f: => Lang => Request[T] => Result)
                      (implicit request: Request[T]) = {
  f(Lang(FRENCH))(request).withLang(Lang(FRENCH))
}
```

Worked great. Now that I am migrating to 2.4, I get the following error

> value withLang is not a member of play.api.mvc.Result

I don't see anything about this in the migration manual, any idea on the equivalent of `withLang` in 2.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withLang` is now in [`ResultWithLang`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.i18n.I18nSupport$ResultWithLang). Mixin [`I18nSupport`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.i18n.I18nSupport) to get an implicit conversion:

```
class blabla with I18nSupport {
  def defaultLanguage[T](f: => Lang => Request[T] => Result)
                        (implicit request: Request[T]) =
    f(Lang(FRENCH))(request).withLang(Lang(FRENCH))
}
```